# Работа с Shell с помощью скриптов Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Я новичок.
Хочу написать несколько скриптов для автоматизации процессов работы с сервером на Python.
Прочитал про модуль subprocess. Пытался его применить:

```
import subrocess

IP = '***'
PASS = '***'

connect = subprocess.run(["ssh", "root@"+IP])
```

А вот как дальше передать пароль, я не понимаю.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Спасибо!

Comment: [не надо ждать ввода](https://serverfault.com/q/241588), [если всё же хотите](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8475290).

Comment: @Стас модуль `requests` применяется совершенно для других вещей: HTTP, а не SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя модуль `pubprocess` будет очень трудно работать по SSH. Лучше используйте специализированную библиотеку для работы с SSH, например **Paramiko**:

- [Пример использования на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/150047/)
- [Пример использования на "Python для сетевых инженеров"](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/19_ssh_telnet/paramiko.html)
- [Официальная документация (eng)](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать утилиту  sshpass

```
import os

ip = ""
password = ""

os.system(f"sshpass -p {password} ssh root@{ip}")
```

Comment: Я не работал с subprocess, но суть думаю ясна

Comment: Это рабочий вариант. Но для него должна быть установлена эта утилита. Если она не установлена, то возможно потребуется ввод пароля sudo-пользователя. А как это автоматизировать?)

Comment: @SlavaOvsyankin тогда можно просто использовать ssh ключ, для этого даже утилит вроде sshpass не потребуется

Comment: @SlavaOvsyankin к тому же ssh ключ на много безопасней, так что лучше использовать его

Comment: По моей задумке, это скрипт должен помогать настроить сервер. Т.е. я приобретаю услугу vps, запускаю скрипт и этот скрипт все мне настраивает. Я пока в самом начале пути, Соответственно доступ по ssh  на сервере еще не настроен.

Comment: @SlavaOvsyankin Посмотрите в сторону ansible или аналогичных продуктов. Не стоит создавать собственные велосипеды/скрипты, если уже есть много готовых продуктов. Кстати, ansible умеет в питон.

Comment: @AK Спасибо. Обязательно изучу вопрос.